# PowerShell get-winevent via invoke-command does not like array

Tags: powershell

explain me this mystery:
on a server I can do:

```
$lastdate=(get-date).adddays(-19)
get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{LogName='setup'; StartTime=$lastdate;id=@(2,3,4)}|sort timecreated
```

and it shows events
but if I try to do it via invoke-command from another server in a domain it does not work with parameter id=$eventids and I get no events

```
$lastdate=(get-date).adddays(-19)
$eventids=@(2,3,4)
$evts=invoke-command -cn $hostname -argumentlist $lastdate,$eventids -scriptblock {
 param($lastdate,$eventids)
 Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName='setup'; StartTime=$lastdate;id=$eventids}|sort timecreated
}
```

$evts: No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.

However if I remove id=$eventids or replace $eventids with @(2,3,4) like in the first example it works! Why is that? The variable $eventids is passed fine, I can add it in the scriptblock and it then appears in $evts as a result of invoke-command

Comment: I don't see a reason off the top.  However what I'd do to test is to dump your vars on the remote server to a text file in your scriptblock to make sure they're passing as expected.  I've also recently run into an issue where aliases are not present under some remoting contexts.  You might try verb-nouning every command as well.

Comment: Does it work if you use the ```Invoke-Command``` version locally on the target server (without the ```-cn hostname```)? I'm wondering whether this is a remoting issue or an ```-argumentlist``` issue...

Comment: invoke-command locally works fine and finds events: 
invoke-command  {get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{LogName='setup'; StartTime=$lastdate;id=$eventids}|sort timecreated}

Answer (score 1):

You're not using "invoke-command -argumentlist" to pass in the local variables. (EDIT:  I see it now) But even then invoke-command has a problem with arrays [with one argument anyway].  I would define the variables inside the invoke-command scriptblock.  @() is not necessary to create arrays.

I've seen this before.  I just made a bug report:  [get-winevent inside invoke-command can't handle arrays inside filterhashtable](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13108)

Answer (score 1):

I honestly have no idea why, but if I do a `Write-Host` or `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1` before the `Get-WinEvent` call and do a cast to `[array]` or `[int[]]` on the $eventids variable, it seems to work just fine.

```
$lastdate = (Get-Date).adddays(-19)
$eventids = 2,3,4
$evts = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -ArgumentList $lastdate, $eventids -ScriptBlock {
    param($lastdate, $eventids)
    # either Write-Host or Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1 seem to add enough delay
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1
    # without the cast [array] or [int[]] you'll still get the error message
    # "No events were found that match the specified selection criteria."
    Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName='setup'; StartTime=$lastdate;id=[int[]]$eventids} | Sort-Object timecreated
}
$evts
```

You can also do the cast in the param block:

```
param($lastdate, [int[]]$eventids)
```

instead of doing that in the hashtable.

<sup>I'm using PowerShell 5.1.18362.752</sup>

Comment: Or define $eventids inside the scriptblock first.

Comment: @js2010 Yes, but that would be hardcoding the event ids in the scriptblock and the OP apparently does not want that.

Comment: I'm just adding information.  You're lucky there's 2 params.  1 array param wouldn't normally work with invoke-command.